# Jetpack Compose LazyList not showing items correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

world!

I've been playing with Jetpack Compose for a while, and I've had really good results.
However, I found this problem: I have a list of items, and I use a `LazyColumn` to show them to the user. But when I scroll up and down, some items are not displayed correctly and they show up like there is no information in them.

I don't know if I'm missing something or this behavior will be corrected in the future.

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZs0l.jpg)

My code:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxHeight(),
) {
    items(expenses, Expense::id) { expense ->
        ExpenseItem(expense = expense, areExpensesSelectable,
            onExpenseLongClick = { onExpenseLongClick?.invoke() },
            onExpenseSelected = { onExpenseSelected?.invoke(it) },
            onExpenseDeselected = { onExpenseDeselected?.invoke(it) })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code for `ExpenseItem` and also the section where this list is used (where the `expenses` list is created). It would be helpful for us to find the cause and provide a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728388/jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-does-not-render-some-items-if-animated-scroll-is-int/67729021#67729021

Comment: Yes, I bumped the version up to beta08 and it was fixed. For some reason I was still working with beta07. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hear this bug is fixed in the latest version of Compose.

Comment: Indeed it was! For some reason, I was still using beta07 instead of beta08. But once I bumped it up it worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Self response: this was a bug present in Jetpack Compose until fixed in version beta08.

Comment: It's wonderful that your problem is solved. You should mark my answer as the solution so that others know that the question has been answered, and do not answer multiple times, thanks.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. It was my first post on Stack Overflow and I forgot to do it. There you go. :D